# Этимология слова "облапошить"

Tags: этимология

Облапошить — обмануть, надуть. А какая у этого слова этимология?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В семнадцатитомном академическом «Словаре современного русского литературного языка» слово *облапошить* квалифицируется как просторечное и, согласно историко-лексикографической справке, указывающей на словарь П. Соколова (1834), как укоренившееся в русском литературном языке с 30-х годов XIX в. Иллюстрации его употребления приведены из «Идиота» Достоевского, «Двух гусаров» Л. Толстого, «Сельской аптеки» Н. Успенского и пьесы Горького «Егор Булычев и другие».
. Глагол *лапошить* и *облапошить* в крестьянских диалектах имеет значение «1. красть, лапить; 2. обманывать, надувать».  В. И. Чернышев отметил употребление слов *облапошить*, *лапошить*, *лапошенье* в подмосковных говорах: «Аблапошили? — Како лапошинья!..»  Были также распространены преимущественно в среднерусских и севернорусских говорах. Оттуда они и попали в язык русской художественной реалистической литературы. В южновеликорусских говорах глагол *лапошить* употребляется в значении `бить' (воронежский говор). *Облапошить* вошло в литературную речь из областных говоров через жаргоны